# Cambio de un dato de un .txt con millones de datos

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo

Tengo un archivo `txt` con una 16 millones de filas, y tiene como cabecera `RUC`;`NOMBRE O RAZÓN SOCIAL`. necesito cambiar `NOMBRE O RAZÓN SOCIAL` a solo `Razón Social`.
intente usando las siguientes funciones pero no realiza ningun cambio.

```
def procesar_header(self, chunk):
    if 'NOMBRE O RAZÓN SOCIAL' in chunk:
        chunk = chunk.replace('NOMBRE O RAZÓN SOCIAL', 'Razón Social')
    return chunk

def limpiar_data(self):
    with open(self.__txt_final, 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as entrada, open(self.__terminado, 'w', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as salida:
        cabecera_modificada = False
        while True:
            chunk = entrada.read(100000)
            if not chunk:
                break
            if not cabecera_modificada:
                chunk = self.procesar_header(chunk)
                cabecera_modificada = True
            salida.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Y te sale algun error? Ya debugeaste?

Comment: Tu código podría dar falsos positivos. Prueba cambiando el primer registro de tu csv a `"a";"NOMBRE O RAZÓN SOCIAL"` y verás como esa fila sufre una modificación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código es correcto en el sentido de que no debería pasar por alto la cadena sin substituirla, pero hay un punto muy importante que puede hacer que pase lo que comentas, la codificación real del archivo de lectura.

Pongamos que tu archivo es en realidad un archivo con codificación UTF-8 y no Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1), la cadena 'NOMBRE O RAZÓN SOCIAL' no se codifica igual en ambos casos (se muestra la cadena codificada en hexadecimal):

```
UTF-8:
4e 4f 4d 42 52 45 20 4f 20 52 41 5a c3 93 4e 20 53 4f 43 49 41 4c
                                   |_____|
                                      Ó
LATIN-1:
4e 4f 4d 42 52 45 20 4f 20 52 41 5a d3 4e 20 53 4f 43 49 41 4c
                                   |__|
                                    Ó
```

UTF-8 es una codificación de longitud variable, donde un carácter puede ser representado por mas de un byte. Latin-1 es una codificación que usa un solo byte por carácter, por lo que solo pude representar los primeros 256 code points de Unicode.

Ambas codificaciones representa igual los primeros 127 code points, pero del 128 en adelante UTF-8 empieza a usar dos bytes. Por eso la codificación es la misma en todos los caracteres de la cadena menos en la O mayúscula con acento agudo.

Si tu archivo esta codificado usando UTF-8 y lo lees usando 'ISO-8859-1' interpretara los dos bytes de la Ó en UTF-8 como si cada uno fueran caracteres individuales, es decir:

```
c3 -> Ã
93 -> No usado
```

Eso luego pasa a UTF-8, que es como Python codifica sus cadenas, con lo que al final tu cadena leída del archivo en UTF-8 es (codificada):

```
b'"RUC";"NOMBRE O RAZ\xc3\x83\xc2\x93N SOCIAL"\n'
```

que no es desde luego lo mismo que:

```
b'"RUC";"NOMBRE O RAZ\xc3\x93N SOCIAL"\n'
```

por lo que `if 'NOMBRE O RAZÓN SOCIAL' in chunk` jamas se cumple.

El error en este caso es completamente silente, no tendrás ningún error de codificación por parte de `read()`.

Por lo tanto, asegurate de usar la codificación correcta que ese archivo usa. No siempre es sencillo detectar la codificación de un archivo sin mas datos que su contenido, hay casos en los que simplemente se puede intentar deducir e ir probando, pero dada la universalidad de UTF-8 es el primer candidato.

---

Por otro lado, si tu archivo es el típico csv con la cabecera (primera linea) `"RUC";"NOMBRE O RAZÓN SOCIAL"`, no necesitas leerlo en fragmentos explícitamente, basta con escribir la cabecera correcta en el archivo de salida y a continuación copiar el archivo de entrada en el de salida descartando la primera linea. [shutil.copyfileobj](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) es muy útil para esto, algo como:

```
import shutil

def limpiar_data(self):
    with (open(self.__txt_final, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as entrada,
          open(self.__terminado, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as salida):
        entrada.readline() # Descartamos la primera linea
        salida.write('"RUC";"Razón Social"\n') # Escribir la cabecera
        shutil.copyfileobj(entrada, salida) # Copiar el resto del archivo
```

Si tu cabecera es siempre `"RUC";"Razón Social"`, con el mismo separador, etc, puedes simplemente escribirla tal cual. Si es variable entonces deberás generarla dinamicamente (con `str.replace` o con el método mas apropiado para el caso)

Comment: Recomiendo modificar el encabezado usando el modulo csv para no tener que reescribir todo el encabezado: `header = next(csv.reader(old_file, delimiter=";")); header[1] = ...; csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, lineterminator="\n").writerow(header)`